# Convert date string object to another format

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

```
'Mon, 15 Jul 2013 14:27:39 -0700'
```

This is the format I have to work with. I'm not sure what format it is in.

However, I want to convert it to a string like this:

```
On Mon, 15 Jul 2013 at 2:27pm
```

I don't want to use basic regex or splitting spaces.  I want to know the right "date" conversion way

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime

Comment: One day in the far future, when he has asked 30,000 questions, TIMEX is going to discover Google, and the search facility on this site. And there will be great rejoicing all over the land.

Comment: @Pekka웃 *Tear*...what a beautiful story

Comment: 1,313 Questions vs 56 answers.WOW!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/U8Mcm/)***

This looks like a situation where you are going to have to do some custom formatting based on knowing the exact format of the input. You should probably take a sliding window approach using substring with a hardcoded knowledge of the format.

(I used jQuery here for brevity in the demo. Note that the actual formatting is pure javascript.)

```
var t = $("#date").text();
$("#sol").html(function(){
 var result = "On ";
 var sub = t.substr(0,17);
 t = t.substr(17);
 result += sub + "at ";
 var pre = t.substr(0,2);
 t = t.substr(2,3);
 var suffix = "am";
 if( parseInt(pre) > 11 ){
   suffix = "pm";
   if( pre != 12 ){
     pre = parseInt(pre) - 12;   
   }
 }
 result += pre + t + suffix;
 return result;
});
```